# Arduino stops responding after writing to I2C

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm currently experimenting with writing to EEPROMs over I2C. Reading goes fine and I get excellent throughput. However when I try to write to the device, the Arduino stops responding, and I have to reset it in order to get it to work again.

The I2C write also doesn't show up in my I2C debugger.

[image: I2c Debug trace]

```
void i2cWrite(unsigned char device, unsigned char memory, const char *wrBuf, unsigned short len) {
  int i = 0;
  ushort bytesWritten = 0;
  ushort _memstart = memory;
  ushort blockSize = 4;
  #ifdef DEBUG_MSGS
  char serialBuf[255] = { '\0'};
  Serial.print("Writing To i2c: ");
  sprintf(serialBuf, "%p", wrBuf);
  Serial.println(serialBuf);
  #endif //DEBUG_MSGS
  while (bytesWritten < len) {
    Wire.beginTransmission((int)device);
    Wire.write((unsigned char)_memstart);
    for (int j = 0; i < blockSize; j++) {
      Wire.write(wrBuf[bytesWritten + j]);
    }
    Wire.endTransmission();
    bytesWritten += blockSize;
    _memstart += blockSize;
    delay(25);
  }
  #ifdef DEBUG_MSGS
  Serial.println("\mDone writing.");
  #endif //DEBUG_MSGS
}
```

I'm quite unsure as to what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the following output over the serial connection:

> Write Request Received: Andy
>
> Writing To i2c: 0xa800fd98

"Writing to i2c" always gives the same value, and it always seems to crash straight after.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `wrBuf` is a pointer, which means you should use the [`(s)printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format `"%p"`. Using mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. Furthermore, symbols beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved in all scopes for the compiler and standard library. Don't define such symbols yourself, even as preprocessor macros.

Comment: What is your EEPROM chip type? Is it one byte or two bytes address IC? Your code only handle one byte address. Probably that causing the problem. Or, as already pointed out, the problem could be related to misused of  `sprintf` function.

Comment: Take care these eeproms need always the command "write enable" followed by the real writing followed by the command "write disable"

Comment: The Eeprom Chip takes a 7-bit adress,  this is supposed to be a transparant interface. the eeprom password is written first  in the code calling this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error seemed to be located in the loop as the output is

```
Write Request Received: Andy
Writing To i2c: 0xa800fd98

I'm working here
I wrote the memory adress
I wrote a byte of data
I wrote a byte of data
I wrote a byte of data
I wrote a byte of data
I wrote a byte of data
....
```

this seems to go on ad infinitum.

After adding a few more debug statements and changing the points Some programmer dude noticed

```
{
    Wire.beginTransmission((int)device);
    Serial.println("I'm working here");
    Wire.write((unsigned char)_memstart);
    Serial.println("I wrote the memory adress");
    for (int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++) {
        Wire.write(wrBuf[bytesWritten + j]);
        Serial.println("I wrote a byte of data");
        //Serial.write(wrBuf[bytesWritten + j]);
    }
    Wire.endTransmission();
    Serial.println("I ended the transmission");
    bytesWritten += blockSize;
    _memstart += blockSize;
    delay(25);
}
```

i noticed that i was checking for I < blocksize (copied from the reading part,) now i'm running into some other (small) issues but this solved the problem i was having.